# Trying to grab number after specific string in the contents of a call using curl

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am using CURL to to get information from a form submission. I am then taking the string of data returned searching for the word "Error" and based on whether it is found redirecting and logging the error into a txt file. Everything works fine except I need to get the error number in the string. To do that I am trying to find the word "Error" and then grabbing and numbers that come after it. However something is wrong as nothing is printing for the error number. When I try to output the results of the pregmatch used I just get NULL. My code is below.

```
$Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);

ob_start();
 header("Content-Type: text/html");
$Temp_Output = $Rec_Data;

if(strpos($Temp_Output,"Error")>=0){

   preg_match("/Error (\d+)/", $Temp_Output, $error);
   var_dump ($error[1]); //prints NULL and when printing $error it is an empty array.

}



}
```

Comment: What about $error[0] is your value there?

Comment: also give an output string example with the numbers to extract...

Comment: $error[0] also gives NULL.  For an output string all I want is any number that comes after the word Error.  So if Error 2 was found then I want to print out the 2.