# Need help grabbing the number after a specific word in a long string

Tags: php, regex, curl

I have this long string that I received from using CURL to grab data from a form post.  In this long string I need to find the word "Error" and then grab any numbers that come after it.  So if during the search it finds "Error 2" I need to grab the 2 and display it.  My problem is that when I try to print it out I am getting NULL and an empty array.  My code is below.

```
$Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);

ob_start();
 header("Content-Type: text/html");
$Temp_Output = $Rec_Data;

if(strpos($Temp_Output,"Error")>=0){

   preg_match("/Error (\d+)/", $Temp_Output, $error);
   var_dump ($error[1]); //prints NULL for $error[0] and $error[1] and when printing $error it is an empty array.

}
```

Here is my CURL code

```
$PostVars = "lname=" . $lname . "&fname=". $fname . "&uid=" . $uid . "&rsp=" . $rsp . "&z1=" . $z1 . "&module=" . $module . "&CFID=" . $CFID . "&CFTOKEN=" . $CFTOKEN;
 $ch = curl_init(POSTURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    , $PostVars);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);

 var_dump ($Rec_Data);
 ob_start();
 header("Content-Type: text/html");
 $Temp_Output = $Rec_Data;
```

Comment: Can you show use the `Rec_Data` output ?

Comment: It would help to see what is that string you received using CURL... That way, we have a better idea of what might be wrong with your current regex

Comment: Also, you should have edited [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18664254/1578604) instead of posting another one.

Comment: Maybe I am not doing the CURL wrong because the output of Rec_Data is giving me bool(false).  However there must be some type of string with the word "Error" in it as the if statement using strpos returns true.

Comment: How about directly printing `$Rec_Data` then? Maybe try `preg_match("/Error.*/", $Temp_Output, $error);` and print `$error[0]`?

Comment: var_dump($Rec_Data) fives me bool(false).  print_r($Rec_Data) and echo $Rec_Data are printing nothing.  When I tried preg_match("/Error.*/", $Temp_Output, $error); and printed out $error[0]; it also printed nothing.  It seems that would mean "Error" is not being found, but that is weird as it enters the if statement " if(strpos($Temp_Output,"Error")>=0)" which means that "Error" is in the string right?

Comment: "Error" is there if strpos() !== false, see @Jerry answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), `strpos` returns `false` when nothing is found.

Try using this in your `IF` instead:

```
if(strpos($Temp_Output,"Error") !== false ) {
    // Do other things
}
```

Since `false >= 0` evaluates to true in PHP well... you always get into the `IF` no matter what.

Disclaimer: I didn't know how `strpos` worked prior to posting this answer.

Comment: Yes, a test for 'false' seems needed, ie !== false. Go figure, a double test of a return value. 0 = position and false, hahaha ...

Comment: I guess the big question is, does 0 == false ? And what about !strpos(), or value != strpos()... wait, unless its 'false'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'Error' is not on page.
Try

```
 Error\s*(\d*)
```

If you have string interpolation try

```
 "/Error\\s*(\\d*)/"
```

Not a php user, but if single quote, try

```
 '/Error\s*(\d*)/'
```

If its like Perl, the delimeter is the quote

```
 /Error\s*(\d*)/
```

Comment: None of those seem to work.  Error must be on the page somewhere as the program enters the if statement   if(strpos($Temp_Output,"Error")>=0)

Comment: Try using `preg_match('/(?<=Error)\s+(\d+)/', $Temp_Output, $error); var_dump($error);` Or start debugging your script.

Comment: @Jake Funchion - Well thats odd, the reason I used \s*\d* means that matches "Error" all by itself. So "Error" is not really there as far as the regex is concerned. Try case insensitive, (?i)error\s*(\d*) - I don't know php.